# R- Assign week number to a series of week days

Tags: r, days

I would like to assign a week number to a series of week days (like "mon", "tue", "wed"..). My dataset are like this:

```
2014    
wed        
thu
fri
sat
sun
mon
tue
```

And I would like to create a new column like this:

```
2014     Week 2014  
wed          1
thu          1 
fri          1
sat          1
sun          1
mon          2
tue          2
```

But this code have to work for every year, regardless of starting date.
Thanks

Comment: where is the code ?!

Comment: I have not a code. I meant that I need a code that works not only for a specific year.

Comment: I suggest you try first , and if your code doesn't work for some reason then you can post it , this way you can get more answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x <- c("wed","thu", "fri", "sat", "sun", "mon", "tue")
cumsum(x == "mon") + (x[1] != "mon")
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
```

Comment: No, I'm sorry. It works!! Thank you Roland and sorry guys for my ignorance.

Comment: You can tick the question in order to accept it, and we could remove all these comments as well.